Should the "Can I answer my own question?" guide mention question quality standards?
We encourage questions with instant self-answers, like How do I return the response from an asynchronous call? and How do I melt a pandas dataframe?. This category of questions contains some of the most useful content on the site.
The trouble is that other of these questions don't stand on their own without the instant self-answer and tend to be low-quality, essentially a placeholder or strawman to facilitate the one answer. Often, the question is too broad, blatantly off-topic, hyper-specific to OP, is an XY problem, or doesn't contain enough context such that another user might reasonably answer the question.
Examples include:

Error: apiRequestContext.get: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND Playwright
Unable to get Laravel Spatie/Browsershot working with Puppeteer, Ubuntu 24.04, PHP 8.3, Chrom & Nginx
PuppeteerSharp fails to display base64-encoded images in PDF output
How do I configure eslint for playwright?
Cypress / percy snapshots don't show canvas content

The current text on self answering in our help center makes no mention of quality, which is well-established in meta answers like this one. Would it be useful to add a paragraph like this to the help center guidelines?

When asking a question with the intent to self-answer, ensure the question adheres to our normal guidelines for questions and is answerable by other users.

This text is just an initial proposal, open for adjustment.
I understand some instant self-answered questions wind up being useful even if the question is otherwise low-quality. Here's an example: Minimal Hibernate 4 XML configuration with Spring 3 for annotation based transaction management and object mapping?. This is somewhat borderline--I can easily see this question not working out well, but it appears to have been useful by virtue of the self-answer, a common scenario.
I don't think the additional question quality guideline proposed here will have the unintended side effect of discouraging these borderline-quality instant self-answer questions, and might help steer them towards excellent self-answered questions, like CanvasContext2D drawImage() issue [onload and CORS], which I'd like to see more of.
My fundamental premise is that the question in an FAQ or instant self-answer is as important to making the thread useful as the answer is, by establishing proper context and enabling other answers that might be worthwhile additions to OP's self-answered solution.

I feel like the paragraph could use a little motivation. Here's an idea: "Keep in mind you're writing the question and answer to be useful by others (who might not have all the context of the problem) as well as yourself in the future (and you might not remember)."

@ggorlen I think [meta-tag:support] does the job (or you can add FR if you want and take out discussion).

I feel like there should be separate FAQs for "Can I answer my own question?" and "Can I ask a question I already know the answer to?". The former is useful when the user figures out the answer themselves after having asked it (often due to comments).

I like this! I think the answer quality standard is just as important, which is perhaps worth taking a note of. ThomA suggested the following:

If you intend to self-answer a question, ensure that you adhere to our guidelines for both questions and answers for the respective posts, and that your question is answerable by other users.

